# pandas apply function (UDF) fails to return multiple values in case the dataframe is empty

Tags: python, pandas, apply, user-defined-functions

I want to be able to return more than a single columns from a pandas UDF (apply function). This works nicely, as long as the data frame is non empty!
In case it is empty it fails with: `not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)`. Is this to be considered as a bug in pandas? Or should the user be forced to manually check the length of the filtered data frame before executing the function? Or is there a better way not to run into this problem?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2,3], 'bar':[4,5,6]})

def my_function(x):
    #print(x)
    # some computation
    # returns multiple values (tuple)
    # simplified here
    return 1,1,1

df = df[df.foo > 10]
df['r1'], df['r2'], df['r3'] = zip(*df.apply(my_function, axis=1))
df
```

Comment: umm i wont take so much pain ill just write something like this `df['r1'], df['r2'], df['r3'] = zip(*df.apply(my_function, axis=1)) if not df.empty else ([],[],[])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use `pd.concat` in combination with `result_type='expand'`.

```py
cols = {0: 'r1', 1: 'r2', 2: 'r3'}
df = pd.concat([df, df.apply(my_function, axis=1, result_type='expand')], axis=1).rename(columns=cols)
```

You have to rename the columns afterwards. Also, the resulting empty dataframe repeats the first two columns:

Output:

```
    foo bar foo bar
```

versus

```
    foo bar
```

Both dataframes are empty, so it may be of no interest for you.

---

I think to check for empty dataframes in pandas is good practice. So, Siddhants solution in the comment is just fine.